# Sonar database date format

Tags: java, date, persistence, data-migration, sonarqube

I am running into an issue today, where Sonar, during the setup migration process, inserts dates with the English format while our SQL Server instance expects the French format (and this cannot be changed).

We have tested several drivers for SQL Servers but the issue still isn't solved.

Any idea how this could be solved ?
Or, at least, do you know which module of Sonar (see Github) is the web application handling this ?

Thanks in advance!

Rolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are normally stored as numeric [EPOCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) values within the database, so the issue you're struggling with is how to represent the date data when serialised during the migration process.

Details of your migration process are sketchy, so I'll assume that you're dealing with some sort of database dump. I'm guessing the "English" date format you refer to is a variation on the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, namely:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

What I suggest is reading the date fields into the database as converted strings (Use the SQL Server [convert](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) function).

Comment: Hi, we finally ended up changing the date format on the DB server side, and removed all but the default MSSQL driver shipped with Sonar... and it just works!

Comment: I'll validate your answer anyway, as to reward your effort ^^